# Changing jQueryMobile CSS attribute in C# code-behind

Tags: c#, asp.net, jquery-mobile

Good day!

I have this:

```
<div data-role="collapsible">
        <h3 runat="server" id="myID">
                ISA Testing
        </h3>
        <p>
                Important content.
        </p>
</div>
```

I want to change the "h3" background color of a jQueryMobile collapsible header based on some logic in the C# code-behind. After I get a handle to the "h3" node, I'm trying to do this in my code-behind:

```
h.Style["background"] = "red";
```

It doesn't work. Any pointers on how I might be able to make this work? The .NET runtime is classifying the "h3" node as a `HtmlGenericControl`, if that has any importance.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

In your code behind you will want to do

```
 myID.Attributes.Add("CssToAdd","ValueForCss");
```

so for color:

```
 myID.Attributes.Add("Color","Red");
```

Comment: This isn't working for me. I've tried `Attributes["background"] = "red"`, `Style["background"] = "red"`, `Attributes.Add("background", "red")`, and `Style.Add("background", "red")`. Do I need to do something special because I'm using jQueryMobile???

Comment: Try background-color instead.  http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_background-color.asp

Comment: Nope. My guess is there is something going on behind the scenes with jQueryMobile. I can't change the color even if I specify it in the .aspx markup using the "style" attribute. Any other ideas?

Comment: What's interesting is if I move the ID ("myID") up and put it on the main collapsible div (`<div data-role="collapsible" runat="server" id="myID">`) the background of the CONTENT turns red. I just can't figure out how to get the stinking header, with the icon on the left, to change color.